# How to prevent SQL injection In App Engine JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Please Help..

How to prevent SQL Injection at the Time of JDO INSERTION?

My JDO class is MyData.Java

```
package com.jdo;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;


@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,detachable="true")
public class MyData{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private String address;


    @Persistent
    private Date addedDate;

    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param address
     */
    public MyData(String id,String name,String address) {
        super();
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.address=address;
        this.addedDate = new Date();
    }


    /**
     * @return id
     */
    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return name;
     */
    public String getname(){
        return this.name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return addedDate
     */
    public Date getAddedDate(){
        return this.addedDate;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     */
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param addedDate
     */
    public void setaddedDate(Date addedDate){
        this.addedDate=addedDate;
    }


}
```

And i tried to insert using

```
MyData user=new MyData ("id001","Shana","Address");                 
user=MyDataDAO.saveData(user);
```

It is saving in table successfully..But i need to prevent it from SQL Injection...Please Help?

Comment: Are you sure the framework doesn't already prevent SQL injection if used right?

Comment: Are you using Cloud SQL or the datastore? Because the latter doesn't even use SQL, so injection is not a problem.

Comment: So there is no SQL as said above ...

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection occurs when you create queries by concatenating strings of plain text with strings of SQL.

You don't need to worry if

1. You're creating queries using prepared statements (which properly quote all values under the hood including untrusted ones), or
2. You're using a good ORM which creates the queries by plugging object fields into a prepared statement or is careful to escape data values properly when serializing messages to the datastore.

The code above looks like it falls into category 2.

Comment: as the O/P later mentioned, using GAE/Datastore so not even an SQL datastore